# Only in Linux; org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "table_name" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, hibernate

I've been looking around Stack Overflow and forums but no luck so far. I have a Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE, JPA/Hibernate stack.

I have a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (...)
```

I've created the table without quotes and in lower case. It works well in local. In local I am in a Windows env with Amazon Corretto jdk11.0.8_10.

Now I have created an AWS RDS PostreSQL DB instance. It is hosted on a Linux.
When I connect from my Windows to the DB, it works fine. But when I deploy my app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, when Hibernate tries to query the DB, I have the error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "table_name" does not exist.
```

My Entity looks like

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class User {
    
}
```

The table is in the default `public` schema.

My `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${RDS_HOSTNAME}:${RDS_PORT}/${RDS_DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=${RDS_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${RDS_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.default_schema=public
```

It doesn't matter if I put the schema or not in the `@Table`.
The only difference I can spot is the environment. Windows versus Linux. When I launch the app locally and use the AWS RDS DB it works.

Comment: can you try `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public` ?

Comment: hi, this is the last line of the application.properties in my post ;)

Comment: No, It's not same na, btw change your `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to `create` or `update` (please backup your DB if have your data)

Comment: I did set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `update` like you suggested it. And it worked in the sense of it created the table. But the thing is, I don't know where! I filled it with some data trough the app but when I connect to the DB with DBeaver as the username, I see the public schema but there is nothing. It is like there is an hidden schema which contains the tabel and the data Hibernate created. I'm lost!

Comment: In the end it was an issue with the DB name. I don't understand how it can works in local and not when it was deployed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was using the wrong DB name. I was using `postgres` as DB name. Instead it was `ebdb`. I don't understand how I'm allowed to connect via DBeaver or PgAdmin to connect to this `postgres` or how when running the app locally I was able to connect to this DB name and not when the app was deployed in AWS.

The name is mentionned in the doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html

You can also see the name in the AWS RDS Configuration tab of you DB instance.

Answer (score 0):

For diagnostic problem, you should use plain text at

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${RDS_HOSTNAME}:${RDS_PORT}/${RDS_DB_NAME}
# ...
spring.datasource.username=${RDS_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${RDS_PASSWORD}
```

What is your version of Spring Boot, PostgreSQL?

This is sample

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres_demo
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123456

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Note: don't use `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect` , use

```
spring.jpa.database=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: Thhaks for your answer. It is Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE and Postgres 12.3

Comment: hibernate mapping said that table `table_name` doesn't exist. It means that connection information is correct. the problem maybe related to incorrect schema

Comment: That's what I thought first but when I connect my project locally (Windows) to the remote DB it works well. It is happening only when I deploy the project in AWS environment (Linux).

Comment: thanks for your help, it helped me to find that it was not the right DB name.